# String[] args vs (String . . . args)

Tags: java, android

When programming for android, whenever I use an AsyncTask the doInBackground method looks like this.

```
 protected String doInBackground(String... args)
```

But when using the arguments anywhere in that block I can access them like a normal String array for example in my program

```
        @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args)
    {
        String details = "";
        try
        {
            details = facade.getRecipeDetails(args[0]);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return details;
    }
```

Which works fine and I have no problem dealing with it. But I'm wondering why they use (String . . . args) instead of a normal array of Strings. Is it just because in the calling method you can just write something like:

```
 new AsyncHandler.execute("argument1","argument2","argument3",...)
```

instead of creating a new array to pass the arguments? Though we could write

```
new AsyncHandler().execute(new String[]{"Argument1","Argument2"});
```

which is a bit more verbose.

Are (String ...) and String[] synonymous in how they work, but the argument passing is just easier using the former because there is no need to create an array? As far as I can tell, the former also gets translated to a string array in the background so would they both compile to the same code and it's just 'syntactic sugar'?

Comment: `(String ...)` means you can add as much `String` param as you want, `String[]` is one parameter which is an array of strings. `(String ...)` depends upon the first param of `AsyncTask`, it is not always `String`.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani except that you can also call a `String...` as if it's `String[]`

Comment: @ratchetfreak Yes it can act as a `String[]`, but lets assume it was by default `String[]`. It would have been quite a problem to use different `String` param in an array. Instead they gave a flexibility to use `(String ...)`.

Comment: @FaizanRabbani I'm aware that it's not always String, it's just an example =). Same goes for Boolean ... or other things, but I liked to use String due to the main(String[] args) we're familiar with. And you said  'you can pass as much strings as you want', well you can pass quite a few strings with an array.  To me it still seems like you can achieve the same with arrays, though it's less readable and more of a hassle. (Passing an array of arrays for example, would reduce readability a bit). Is it correct that it's mainly for readability then? (thanks already btw)

Comment: @FaizanRabbani well it's a simple wrap of `new String[]{...}` to convert (it's what actually happens when you use a `String...`)

Comment: @DylanMeeus I agree it is absolutely achievable but a bit less readable and more of a hassle. That is why `(String ...)` is more useful (Readability) .

Comment: Okay thanks guys! Feel free to post that as an answer by the way, I'll accept it as it resolved my question ^^

Comment: `...` is purely syntactic sugar in Java.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`(String ...)` is *an array of parameters* of type `String`, where as `String[]` is *a single parameter*.

Now here `String[]` can full fill the same purpose here but `(String ...)` provides more readability and easiness to use.

It also provides an option that we can pass multiple array of `String` rather than a single one using `String[]`.

Comment: While `String[]` can be passed into a method taking `String...` as a parameter, two `String[]`s cannot. There is no implicit array concatenation that takes place here.

Answer (score 5):

A feature of String[] vs String... is that the "String..." does not need to be part of the call.

```
public void test(String... args){ 
   if(args.length > 0){
      for( String text : args){
         System.out.println(text);
      }
   }else{
      System.out.println("No args defined.");
   }
}

public void callerTest(){
     test();
     System.out.println();

     test("tree");
     System.out.println();

     test("dog", "cat", "pigeon");
}
```

Then if you call `callerTest();` the Output will be:

```
No args defined.

tree

dog
cat
pigeon
```